# Argument parsing "library" for bash?

Tags: bash

I know `getopts` but I have to make the parsing and error handling each time.

Does anyone know if there exist a "library" or a set of functions for Bash for parsing command arguments?

E.g. Perl have tons of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [getoptx](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-29/bash/examples/functions/getoptx.bash) is something for you. Although I find getopts really nice and btw.: you should always do some error handling if you use user input ;-)

Comment: It is very neat, but I get a seg. fault after 10 seconds on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. So I guess I have to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

[bash-modules](https://github.com/vlisivka/bash-modules), "arguments" module.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
. import.sh log arguments

NAME="world"

parse_arguments "-n|--name)NAME;S" -- "$@" || {
  error "Cannot parse command line."
  exit 1
}

info "Hello, $NAME!"
```